# Filebeat container to read all docker logs not working

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have the following docker compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
        container_name: elasticsearch
        volumes:
            - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
        restart: always
        environment:
            - discovery.type=single-node
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=changeme
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=false
            - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        healthcheck:
            test: 'curl --fail -s -X POST  -u ''elastic:changeme'' -H ''Content-Type: application/json'' http://localhost:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d ''{"password":"changeme"}'' >/dev/null || exit 0'
            interval: 5s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 5
    filebeats:
        command: filebeat -e -strict.perms=false
        depends_on:
            elasticsearch:
                condition: service_healthy
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.9.0
        container_name: filebeats
        volumes:
            - ./filebeat.docker.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
            - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers
    kibana:
        depends_on:
            - filebeats
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
        container_name: kibana
        ports:
            - 5601:5601
        restart: always
        environment:
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=changeme
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        depends_on:
            - filebeats
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        container_name: mysql
        volumes:
            - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
            - 33060:33060
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user
            MYSQL_DATABASE: changeme
    adminer:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - filebeats
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    nginx:
        depends_on:
            - filebeats
            - kibana
            - adminer
        image: nginx:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "81:81"
            - "82:82"
            - "83:83"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
volumes:
    elasticsearch-data:
        driver: local
    certs:
        driver: local
    mysql-data:
        driver: local
```

I want that every log of these containers are captured by the container of fileeats and send to elastic here the filebeat config

```
filebeat.inputs:
    - type: filestream
      enabled: true
      paths: -/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
      stream: all # can be all, stdout or stderr

#================================ Processors ===================================
processors:
    - add_docker_metadata: ~

#========================== Elasticsearch output ===============================
output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    username: elastic
    password: changeme
# #============================== Dashboards =====================================
# setup.dashboards:
#   enabled: true

#============================== Kibana =========================================
# setup.kibana:
#   host: "${KIBANA_HOST}:80"
#   username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
#   password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
```

but it not seems to work I see that the docker container files are modified but not captured by the filebeats container.

I think the problem is that /var/lib/docker have no permission to read inside the filebeat container so I don't know how to change it ...ot maybe there is a better way to receive log than from the log file (than will be work even on docker desktop that don't use log file)?

Also
I want to know if I can add module to filebeat config file because I dont know the path of the log file because it depends on docker log id and so I can say it before I launch docker compose up.

Comment: Your problem is hard to diagnose without replicating your setup. First, typically I expect to see a volume shared across all containers where the logs are written and then filebeat also has that volume and reads the logs from there. I do not see that in your config? Maybe I am missing it. I think you need to do some more digging yourself first.

Comment: And some other things to consider ... 1. can you shell into the filebeat container and see if it is able to view/read the log files? 2. Do the file names match the pattern you specified `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log`? I do not see config in the non-filebeat containers telling them to put their logs there. 3. Are the logs there at all?

Comment: my problem is that docker not let me change the path to log file ...

Comment: in linux /var/lib/docker/containers contains logs , I tested it ...

Comment: You mean change the path in an application? You can leave the path as default, but mount in a volume at the log location?